# clustered index on "join" column or on "where" column

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables in SQL Server.
Table A has two columns: ID and Name. They are both unique.
Table B is joined to table A on the Name column.

Assuming most of the queries to these tables will be:

```
Select A.Name, B.xyz From A Inner Join B on A.Name = B.Name Where ID = 1
```

Which column in table A do I want to create a clustered index on? ID to speed up the WHERE or Name to speed up the JOIN?

Comment: on second thought, leaving out the "clustered" bit, once sql server finds it's record in table A by satisfying the where clause, it gets it's value for the join from the Name in the same record. it does not have to look further. so could it be that indexing the Name column in table A will have no impact on performance in the example provided?

Comment: That's correct, the index on A.Name does nothing for the query you showed.

Comment: logically, you are right. in reality, according to the sql server execution plan, the tables are always joined before applying the where clause. this might mean entire table A is joined to entire table B.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If ID is unique then any plan will for sure pick it first. Perhaps the statistics are out of date?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want a clustered index at all. You want just a regular index. (Unless you expect to read all the data in sequential order.)

What you do want is an index on both fields together, with `ID` first and `Name` second.

So three indexes:

```
ID Primary
Name Unique
ID, Name Unique
```

The only reason to create the last index is if your database supports index merges. Otherwise you want just the index on `ID`. `A.Name` isn't used from the index, `A.Name` is data, not a search key. You want an index on `B.Name`.

Comment: I don't find uncommon that he'd want to perform queries in sequential order, specially on names.

Comment: are you saying there is no benefit to a clustered index if multiple records are not being queried in sequential order?

Comment: Correct. There is only a benefit if you access in order, in reverse order, or as a range (which includes `>` and `<`). And it does slow down inserts so I wouldn't do it without clear evidence you need it.

Comment: if i may ask, what would you say to the comment i just posted to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The **NAME** column since it's unique and you are more likely to perform searches/joins on this one.

Comment: what if we just consider the performance gain of clustered index. where is it greater, when joining two tables or when using it as a key field?

Comment: clustered indexes are faster because that's the way data is **physically stored**; that's why you can only have one.

Comment: thanks. i understand that. but i am not familiar with how sql server actually goes about it's work of collecting it's data. that's why i'm unsure as to where a clustered index has more impact: when sql server does the work of joining the tables on when it does the work of matching the where clause?

Comment: Join operations are one of the most expensive operations that can be performed so usually the where clause is evaluated first (if an index can be used for this) and the join operation performed last.